# Present a full screen view over the whole app in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm not looking for how to use `.fullScreenCover` as that doesn't work in this case.

What I am looking for is a way to present a full screen view over the entire rest of the app from the root of our app.

It would be a bit like the YouTube app that allows you to browse the list of videos etc... and then when you tap a video it shows in a full screen view but also the rest of the app is still there behind it. You can minimise the video and still browse the videos behind it while it still plays.

I have tried to just use a `.fullScreenCover` from the root of our app but the problem with that is that if there is ever a modal view presented from somewhere else in the app it will not show the full screen as it is "already presenting".

I've also had a look at using multiple windows but that just puts the windows side by side rather than over each other. And it is UNDER any modals shown from elsewhere in the app.

I'm thinking I maybe have to break out into UIKit world to get this working.

Comment: Make your root a `ZStack` containing the popover + rest of the app. or use an overlay there

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini unfortunately that doesn’t work. It will either present incorrectly or complain that it is already presenting.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini if you have at the root of the app a ZStack with the app at the bottom and then an optional view. And then in the app you present a sheet and then in the ZStack you make the optional view appear then the optional view will appear below the sheet. Anything you do in the window group in the main app will be covered by any modal presented view in the app. I'd like something that will go over anything else in the app. A bit like how the YouTube app works.

Comment: You may have to roll your own modals and sheets to make this happen. All of Apple's automatically go on top of your views, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: You can achieve this using `window` but I don't know a native way in the SwiftUI